# Uploadify File not being uploaded even after success message

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify, jquery-file-upload

I am a newbie at coding I am trying to use uploadify in my website. After uploading the files I get a success message but the file is not being uploaded to the folder. I tried debugging the code with all the answers I found on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work. Here's the code for index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <hr>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jquery.uploadify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uploadify.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Uploadify Demo</h1>
  <form>
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
  </form>
  <?php $timestamp=t ime();?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'uploader': 'uploadify.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'uploadify-cancel.png',
        'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
        'script': 'uploadify.php',
        'folder': '/uploads',
        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'queueSizeLimit': 9999,
        'simUploadLimit': 2,
        'sizeLimit': 4000000,
        'checkExisting': false,
        'multi': true,
        'formData': {
          'timestamp': '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
          'token': '<?php echo md5("unique_salt" . $timestamp);?>'
        },
        'auto': true,
        'onUploadError': function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
          alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
        },
        'onUploadSuccess': function(file, data, response) {
          alert('The file ' + file.name + ' was successfully uploaded with a response of ' /*+ response +*/ + ':' + data);
        },

      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the uploadify.php file

```html
<?php
// Define a destination
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root
$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
 $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
 $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
 $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
 
 // Validate the file type
 $fileTypes = array('jpg','JPG','jpeg','JPEG','gif','GIF','png','PNG'); // File extensions
 $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
 
 if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
  move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
  echo '1';
 } else {
  echo 'Invalid file type.';
 }
}
?>
```

And the check-exists.php file

```html
<?php
/*
Uploadify
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
Released under the MIT License <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php> 
*/

// Define a destination
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root and should match the upload folder in the uploader script

if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder . '/' . $_POST['filename'])) {
 echo 1;
} else {
 echo 0;
}
?>
```

PS: I have tried by changing the $targetFolder to uploads, /uploads, /uploads/ but nothing worked.
The folder has 777 permissions
The success message I get is "The file ________ was successfully uploaded with a response of :CWSaa"
I don't know what CWSaa is and how it is echoed.

Please help.

Comment: it's only saying it was successful because the server responded with a 200 status code, meaning there was no server error, however you are likely either by passing the upload code all together or filtering it out. view the respond of your ajax call to figure out the actual problem.

Comment: echo $targetPath in uploadify.php so that you can trace the path where it is being uploaded.

Comment: @Selva kumar I tried to echo the path but it remains blank

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue is with folder path
You are usig 'folder': '/uploads'. It mean uploads folder is in document root directory. If the folder is at same location where code file is then you need to use 'folder': 'uploads'.

Do check other paths you are defining in php too.